# Running time of BFS-based path-finding algorithm

Tags: performance, graph, big-o, dijkstra, breadth-first-search

I came up with a BFS-based path-finding algorithm intended as an alternate to Diskjstra's (to be honest, I suspect other have come up with it in the past, but I can't find any mention of it online anywhere).  I'm trying to figure out what the running time is, but my friends and I are debating it and haven't been able to come up with a definitive answer.  Here's a link to a description and implementation of the algorithm in Go:
https://github.com/joshlf13/bfspath

I am under the impression that the running time is e + e^2 + e^4 + ... + e^2d where e is the average number of edges per vertex and d is the distance of the final shortest path (giving O(e^2d)).  The problem is, this relies on the result of the algorithm which, as my friend points out, shouldn't be included in a consideration of running time.

My reasoning is this: each pass of the BFS increases the number of vertices considered by a multiple of e.  Further, each time a vertex is considered, it's e operations.  Thus, each pass is v (number of vertices in pass) times e.  And if v is 1 then e then e^2, etc, v*e is e + e^2 + e^4, etc.

A different approach is to consider the running time in terms of number of edges considered.  An edge of length N takes N operations.  Thus, for a graph with E edges and an average edge-length of N, it's O(N*E).  However, this only applies to the portion of the graph which is considered during operation of the algorithm, and the size of that subset doesn't scale linearly with the distance between the start and endpoints, which makes a true consideration of O() difficult.

Ideas...?

Comment: How is this faster than dijstra's? This can have horrible performance for graphs which have really long edges...

Comment: It can be faster with small edge lengths. You're right that it can also be horribly slow if edge lengths are long.

Answer (score 0):

So, the most fundamental problem with your algorithm is that it can't guarantee the right answer when edges have real-valued weights/lengths. Unless you are fully prepared to have "unit lengths" that are the smallest floating-point value available on your computer (hint: it's really small), then you won't be able to break up every edge.

Thus, your algorithm only even returns the right answer on graphs that can be reduced to uniform grids in which you can move only horizontally or vertically at any given time.

As for analyzing the runtime, your friend is absolutely correct. There's nothing "difficult" about "a true consideration of O()". Your algorithm is what's called pseudo-polynomial time in complexity theory. What that really means is that it's exponential in the size of the input, but polynomial in the value. In particular, it's O(NE + V), where N is the largest edge weight among all edges in your graph.

Pseudo-poly algorithms on graphs are /way too slow/ for any real-world usage, even if you can guarantee integer edge lengths. You could really only use it on uniform-length grids, and people /already/ use BFS on uniform-length grids; it's just not "a special algorithm", it's BFS.